# How to create an object that belongs to the same class as a given object

Tags: java, oop, reflection

In Ruby, I can do something like:

```
object2 = object1.class.new
```

Can I do the same thing in Java? Is this pattern called reflection?

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection

```
Object object2 = object1.getClass().newInstance();
```

If you know the type of object1 you can do this

```
MyType object1 = ...
MyType object2 = (MyType) object1.getClass().newInstance();
```

Comment: But How to name the type? using `Object`?

Comment: @yozloy The object doesn't have a name, it has a type which you could make the same as object1's type if you like. (You would have to say which it is)  The name of the reference to the object is `object2`

Comment: The problem is the casting type `MyType` is determined by object1, It shouldn't be dynamic I think

Comment: @yozloy In that case you don't know the exact type, it is just an Object.